# Recognizing rectangles in OpenCV Java

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to crop rectangles out of an image using OpenCV/Java.  I've been somewhat successful finding the lines that make up the rectangular sections I want to crop, but I'm having a hard time finding the best way to do the following:

1. Connect the segmented lines I've found (see screenshot below) into separate rectangles (lines can be shared by multiple adjacent rectangles)
2. Determine that a nearly complete rectangle is a rectangle (see broken bottom edge of full rectangle in screenshot, to the left of line #6)

Any guidance is appreciated!

[image: rectangle image]

Comment: Just as an idea, to join the segments you may check if the points describing 2 segments are collinear (in the same line). This may even go over holes... then you can check which segments are perpendicular and parallel, the ones in parallel are possible other sides of the rectangle. With the ones perpendicular you can create the point of intersection and those are the points that create your rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been using OpenCV's `Impgproc.HoughLinesP`, which produced the line segments seen in the question's screenshot. I ended up scrapping that path, opting for a combination of `Imgproc.findContours`, `Imgproc.contourArea` and `Imgproc.boundingRect` instead.  This approach worked for me, and allowed me to avoid writing a bunch of recursive line-combining code.